# Kendo-UI Kendo-drop-down-list with k-filter issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I am using select list with `kendo-drop-down-list`along with `k-filter="'contains'"` to filter the list. The select list is in `ng-repeat`. The issue is when I filter one list and select the a particular option, other list's in `ng-repeat` automatically gets filtered with selected option.

Eg. When I filter one drop down list for string `"foo"` and select `"foo123"` from the list. Other drop downs gets automatically filtered for string `"foo123"`.

```
<select kendo-drop-down-list id="LookUp{{$index}}"
    k-data-text-field="'Text'"
    k-data-value-field="'Value'"
    k-data-source="enrichedValueSource"
    ng-if="data.lookUp.length"
    ng-model="item.EnrichId"
    k-index="'{{item.EnrichId}}'"
    k-filter="'contains'"
    class="full-width m-b form-control" required ng-change="itemChange(item)">
 </select>
```

Images for the issue. 1 [Drop-down with search Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsm9O.png) 
2. [2nd Drop-down automatically binds for search text in 1st Drop-Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c7zv.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all the DropDownLists use a shared DataSource instance - `enrichedValueSource`. As a result, changes triggered when interacting with one of the DropDownList instances, will influence all the other DropDownLists.

If `enrichedValueSource` is a DataSource instance, then switch to a DataSource configuration object. In this way, all the DropDownLists will copy the provided settings and create their own DataSource instance.